# Problema al instalar CPANEL en Centos7 "cPanel does not support NetworkManager"

Tags: cpanel, centos7, vps

Al instalar Cpanel en Centos7 me sale el siguiente error y no comprendo el motivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué sucede?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Hay que desabilitar Network Manager para que se pueda proceder con la instalación sin problemas.

1.Desabilitar  Network Manager:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

2. Ir al directorio /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:

cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

3. Abrir o y si no existe crear ifcfg-ens2 con un editor de texto como por ejemplo "vi text editor":

   vi  ifcfg-ens2

Añadir al archivo estas lineas:

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
```

4. Resetear el network service:

   systemctl enablenetwork.service
   systemctl start network.service

Puedes comprobar que quedó desabiltado:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

Tras estos pasos he podido completar la instalación sin ningún problema.